# sql query to parse varchar2 text to extract number

Tags: sql, oracle

I am newbie in writing sql queries...pls advise

```
I have a below oracle table 
col1          col2  col3
test1: 001    A1    A2
test1: 002    B1    B2
test1: 003    C1    C2
test1: 004    D1    D2
test1: 005    E1    E2
```

I would like to print rows which is having col1 value >=002 and <=004 as below

```
col1          col2  col3
test1: 002    B1    B2
test1: 003    C1    C2
test1: 004    D1    D2
```

col1 is varchar2(150 byte)

how to write query for this?

Comment: Is col1 guaranteed to have the format `test1: 00X`, where only "X" may vary?

Comment: yes. It ganranteed to have that format where X vary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the right digit of the string in col_1 and see if it's between 2 and 4.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM my_table
WHERE CAST(substr(col1,-1,1) AS INTEGER) BETWEEN 2 AND 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions will be your friend here:

```
select t.*
  from tst t
  WHERE TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.col1, '[0-9]{3}')) BETWEEN 2 and 4;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee9efbf/7)

Best of luck.